# Returned error when trying to install Paperclip gem - Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip

I'm going through a [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5W-Y3aROVE) to install the Paperclip gem on my site. Got to the last step but its returning the following error, not sure where I'm going wrong..

Error -

```
NoMethodError in Houses#index
undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
<%= image_tag @house.image.url(:medium) %>
```

When it comes to including the code to display the image in my index.html.erb so I've put in:

```
<%= image_tag @house.image.url(:medium) %>
```

as the tutorial instructed but its doesn't like that & returns an error when I've uploaded the image and refreshed my index page to view the image.

Does anybody have any idea where I'm going wrong?

All relevant code is as follows:

index.html.erb -

```
<h2><%= link_to "Add a House", new_house_path %></h2>

<% @houses.each do |house| %>
<div class="house">
<%= image_tag @house.image.url(:medium) %>
<h2><%= house.title %></h2>
<h2>&#163;<%= house.price %></h2>
<p><%= house.description %></p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

house.rb -

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, presence: true
validates :price, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :image, presence: true

has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "300x300", thumb: "150x150#" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @house, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
<%= form.input :title, label: "House title" %>
<%= form.input :price, label: "House price" %>
<%= form.input :description, label: "Describe your house" %>
<%= form.input :image, as: :file, label: "Image of house" %>
<%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

houses.controller.erb -

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @houses = House.page(params[:page]).per(20).order(created_at: :desc)
end

def new
  @house = House.new
end

def create
  @house = House.new(params.require(:house).permit(:title, :price, :description, :image))
  if @house.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

end
```

Comment: change `image_tag @house.image.url(:medium)` to `image_tag house.image.url(:medium)` (it uses the local varial `house` instead of the non-existing variable `@house`)